# Jquery Validation not working to an input field that's not exist when document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

currently i'm working with Jquery validation. It's working well when form is ready.

But when i try to add new field there with the same name by click button. the  validation is not working.

```
<form id="formInput" autocomplete="off">
       <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 mt-2 mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control hoho" name="name[]" id="name" value="{{ $registData->company_name ?? '' }}" placeholder="input name">
       </div>

       <div class="col-md-4 col-xs-4 mt-2 mb-2">
            <input type="text" class="form-control hoho" name="name[]" id="name" value="{{ $registData->company_name ?? '' }}" placeholder="input name">
       </div>
<button type="button" class="addnew">
</form>
```

e.g. there are two input with the same name directly up there on doc ready. when form submit, both input field is being validated.

Then i press add new button to add more input with the same name. The last input is not validated

try to re-validate when button addnew press but not working

```
 $(".addnew").on('click', function(e) {
                ...
                $("#formInput").validate({
                rules: {
                    'name[]': {
                        required: true,
                       
                    },
                }
                messages: {
                    'name[]': {
                        required: defaultMessageError
                    },

                }
            });
```

I expect the form is validate correctly when form input is edited

Comment: If you generate a new input after the click event on .addnew has been triggered and the validator has been initialized, the new input will not be automatically validated by the jQuery validation plugin. This is because the validation plugin initializes on the form and its inputs at the time the validate() method is called, and it doesn't automatically monitor the addition of new inputs after that initialization.

Comment: Yup, then i try to revalidate it once again after button add new trigger, but it's not getting recall. Should it have a diff name ?

Comment: A: Reset the validator after adding a new input (not recommended), B: Add rules dynamically: `$(document).on("click",".addnew",function(e){e.preventDefault(),$("#formInput").validate({rules:{"name[]":{required:!0}},messages:{"name[]":{required:defaultMessageError}}})});`

Comment: is the second method you've mention, the same way i define at the thread ? because it's not working

Comment: 1: Initialize validation on document ready: `$(document).ready(function(){$("#formInput").validate({rules:{"name[]":{required:!0}},messages:{"name[]":{required:defaultMessageError}}})});`   2. Modify your add new button click event: `$(".addnew").on("click",function(e){$("input[name='name[]']").each(function(){$(this).rules("add",{required:!0,messages:{required:defaultMessageError}})})});`

Comment: Even i try to validate only after button add trigger. It only works to the first name. Except, its define at first load. Even there's multiple same name, it still working.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255654/discussion-between-rafael-dorado-and-lauwis).

Comment: There are a lot of misunderstandings here.  I think you need to review the plugin's documentation.  You cannot call `.validate()` more than once, and when you add fields dynamically, you would use the `.rules()` method to add new rules to the form.  Most importantly, your `name` for the fields must be unique, therefore you need to add an index number to the array... `name[0]`, `name[1]`, etc.

Comment: *"when form submit, both input field is being validated."* - impossible.  When two fields have an identical `name`, both are NOT validated.  Only one is validated and all duplicates are ignored.